# HDD shows blank File System in Disk Management, unknown partition type

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, filesystems, ntfs

So I have a secondary internal HDD that was used as storage on an Ubuntu machine. I did a clean install on the boot drive with Server 2012R2 and the secondary drive shows the capacity in Disk Management but the File System shows as blank.

When running diskpart, listing the partitions for the drive show the partition type as Unknown. Running "convert mbr" in diskpart throws the error "the specified disk is not convertible".

How can I change the file format to NTFS without data loss?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the data to NTFS as it is most probably an EXT4 filesystem.
You can install this driver https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/ to be able to read and write to your Ubuntu/linux partition.